# Unable to execute PHP code from extenal file with GET request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

While learning JQuery and AJAX, I came across some exercises with GET requests to external files. (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp)

My JQuery script is as follows:

```
function displaySuggestions(str) {
    var xhttp;
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("suggestions").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText)
            document.getElementById("suggestions").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q="+str, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Code is executed with following HTML code:

```html
<div>
    <h2>Display sugestions while typing</h2>
    <div>
        <form>
        Fill in employee: <input onkeyup="displaySuggestions(this.value)">
        </form>
        Suggestions: <span id="suggestions"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output of the alert function is the whole PHP file as text.

Not sure if I am doing something wrong with the PHP file itself as I get the same result with an exact copy of the example code from the link above. I have created a file "gethint.php" with an exact copy of the PHP example code displayed at the bottom of the page from the link above

Comment: "The output of the alert function is the whole PHP file as text" - Then it sounds like you don't have PHP configured in your web server. This is a regular GET request, you don't need JavaScript involved to test the PHP part.

Comment: Are you running this code on a webserver with installed php?

Comment: Are you definitely opening your page via a URL to a webserver which can run PHP (and not, for example, via `file://`)?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I was indeed running a server without PHP installed! Forgot that I was working on a local server and not my docker. Thank you!